# Kentico CMS peformance

Tags: performance, kentico

I am exploring CMS open source system based on .net platform which is capable of handing 5000+ users. One of them is kentico CMS. I want to know whether Kentico will give good performance and response in case if 5000+ users are accessing the system.

Answer (score 3):

Kentico is a high performing solution.  5000+ users are just the tip of the iceberg in regards to what Kentico can handle. On Kentico.com website there is a scalability and Performance section.  There's a report you can download which talks about performance in v10.  Version 11 will be as good if not better that described in that report.

References:
https://www.kentico.com/product/all-features/development/scalability-and-performance

http://www.kentico.com/product/resources/brochures/kentico-10-performance-report/kentico10_performance.pdf